# FolderBroserDialog() causes System Error when in 32 bit build

Tags: c#, wpf, folderbrowserdialog

```
        var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        dialog.ShowDialog();
        txtBoxWindowsSourceFolder.Text = dialog.SelectedPath;
```

causes an error  "This program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-|1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. Try Reinstalling the program to fix the problem." When it attempts to ShowDialog().

However, after clicking "OK", the ShowDialog still succeeds in opening up a FolderBrowserDialog model and it even works as intended, allowing you to sucessfully select a folder which then gets its path placed into the text box as it should.  This error only occurs the first time you attempt to use the ShowDialog for the FolderBrowserDialog.  Afterwards the error will no longer present itself until the WPF exe is closed and run again.  This error also does not occur when I change the build's platform target to x64.

Re-downloading the visual studio has fixed the issue on my machine but moving the executable to other machines still results in the error persisting.

I could use help either fixing the error or preventing this pop-up from appearing.

Answer (score -1):

Download or repair the Visual C++ Redistributable:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x64.exe

or try updating Windows.

This should fix your issue.

Comment: Just an FYI, the link I provided is for VS 2015 - you may want to try other versions if that one does not work.

Comment: Issue still persists on other machines

Comment: How many other machines? Have you tried updating the redist on those machines? Try deleting bin and rebuilding.

Comment: You want to download the 32-bit redistributable since that's the platform it doesn't work on. Also at what point are you showing the dialog? During app startup? Lastly, use a library/dialog that doesn't depend on WinForms